# p.value filtration from an lapply-function applied for the function coxph

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm running the survival analysis for each of expression levels of 566 genes. I did this by combining the function `coxph()` with the function `lapply`, and it worked well. Right now, due to the large number of genes considered, I am stuck on how to do P-value filtration in order to only preserve genes with significant survival rates, i.e., when P<0.05.

This is the dummy data:

```
 df1 = structure(list(ERLIN2 = structure(c(`TCGA-A1-A0SE-01` = 1L, `TCGA-A1-A0SH-01` = 1L, 
`TCGA-A1-A0SJ-01` = 1L), .Label = c("down", "up"), class = "factor"), 
    BRF2 = structure(c(`TCGA-A1-A0SE-01` = 2L, `TCGA-A1-A0SH-01` = 1L, 
    `TCGA-A1-A0SJ-01` = 2L), .Label = c("down", "up"), class = "factor"), 
    ZNF703 = structure(c(`TCGA-A1-A0SE-01` = 2L, `TCGA-A1-A0SH-01` = 1L, 
    `TCGA-A1-A0SJ-01` = 2L), .Label = c("down", "up"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c(43.4, 47.21, 13.67), event = c(0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("TCGA-A1-A0SE-01", 
"TCGA-A1-A0SH-01", "TCGA-A1-A0SJ-01"), class = "data.frame")
```

After that, to receive the results, please enter the code lines below:

```
#library
if(!require(survival)) install.packages('survival')
library('survival')

#run survival analysis
df2=lapply(c("ERLIN2",    "BRF2",      "ZNF703"),

       function(x) {

         formula <- as.formula(paste('Surv(time,event)~',as.factor(x)))
         coxFit <- coxph(formula, data = df1)
         summary(coxFit)
       })
```

From here, I'm trying to do P-value filtration as follows:

```
for (i in 3){
    df2 = df2 %>% subset(df2[[i]]$logtest[3] < 0.05)
}
```

But it is inefficient! Any help would be aprriciated!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your list and getting the error, "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: @Mohanasundaram Thank for your warning! It is my fault, and I fixed. Please review again and help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in sub-setting the list by any variable (pvalue of logtest in your case), I would suggest the `rlist` package

```
library(rlist)

df3 <-  list.filter(df2, logtest[["pvalue"]] < 0.05)
```

This will filter the list by the conditions specified. The conditions can be nested as well.

Comment: I saw the request for "p-value filtration and thought I was looking at a request for stochastic integration.